# After upgrading to 18.04, keyboard freezes periodically in Kubuntu

Tags: shortcut-keys, kde, plasma-5

I upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04 and now sometimes the desktop partially freezes. It seems to happen when I use several keyboard shortcuts one after another, like switching virtual desktops, sending windows to virtual desktops, and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>, but it is not consistent.

When it locks up, the whole desktop freezes for a moment, then I get control of the mouse back, but no keyboard shortcuts work and I cannot close windows. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> does not get me to a virtual console and I have to reboot manually.

I followed advice from a similar issue to install the kde desktop package backport from 18.10. After doing so, I've experienced the issue much less frequently (2-3 times in as many weeks), but it's still happened a few times.

I'm not sure if the SysReq key is configured (it doesn't work, but maybe just not configured) and I do not have <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> configured to reset/exit the X Server, which might be worth changing if the issue persists.

Any idea how to fix it? And should I file a bug report somewhere?

Comment: • Upgrades may sometimes be glitchy. • Re. filing a bug, you can do so at https://bugs.kde.org. However, triaging an intermittent problem maybe difficult. But give it a try. • You can also get more eyes on your issue by asking at [Kubuntu Forums](https://www.kubuntuforums.net), or [KDE Community Forums](https://forum.kde.org), or [reddit/kde](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/) or [reddit/kubuntu](https://www.reddit.com/r/Kubuntu/).